# Lyapunov function for 2D nonlinear system

Tags: convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

The figure below shows a solution to the system of ODEs 
$$\dot{q} = p$$
$$\dot{p} = -\lambda p - V'(q)$$
where $\lambda= 0.1$ and $V'(q) = q - q^3$.
The figure suggests that the system converges to the fixed-point $q=1,p=0$. I want to prove the convergence of the system, by finding a Lyapunov function or finding contraction in some other way.

[image: Solution curves for an initial condition $p=\delta, q=0$. note that the $p$ and $q$ axis were accidently swapped in the 2d figure. From http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~juengel/sde/Lord.pdf]

( solution curves for an initial condition $p=0.1, q=0$. note that the $p$ and $q$ axis were accidently swapped in the 2d figure. From http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~juengel/sde/Lord.pdf)

I tried to look at the Eigenvalues of the Jacobian for the system, but I don't think that the criteria works for this system.

How can I prove that $(q(t), p(t) ) \rightarrow (1,0)$ as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: 1) When $\lambda \neq 0$ analysis of eigenvalues perfectly works here -- for small $\lambda$ equilibria at $(\pm 1, 0)$ are foci and for large $\lambda$ they are nodes. 2) Note however that both of these equilibria are stable: their basins of attraction are separated by separatrices of saddle at $(0, 0)$. 3) When $\lambda = 0$ this system is of form $\ddot{q} = -V'(q)$: it is conservative and its first integral is $\frac{p^2}{2} + V(q)$. Equilibria at $(\pm 1, 0)$ are centers in this case. 4) The same function that was first integral when $\lambda = 0$ is a Lyapunov function in other cases.

Comment: @Evgeny thanks for your insight. I see that the function $H(q,p) = \frac{p^2}{2} + V(q)$ is decreasing along system trajectories (when $p\neq 0$) and now my question is how can I go from here to concluding convergence to $(\pm 1,0 )$?

Comment: Why don't you want to use eigenvalue analysis? This analysis will prove that these eigenvalues have negative real parts and thus equilibria are asymptotically stable. Anyway, just check that $H(q, p)$ is really a Lyapunov function in some neighbourhood of $(\pm 1, 0)$ and you are done. However, this Lyapunov function is a bit useless outside of $\frac{p^2}{2} + V(q) = 0$ (homoclinic figure-eight when $\lambda = 0$).

Comment: @Evgeny what about points far away from the equilibria? For instance, if the system starts at $p=10, q=0$ How can I show convergence to equilibrium in this case?

Comment: You still can use Lyapunov function here :) Study how do level-sets of $H(q, p)$ look like. The decreasing of Lyapunov function corresponds to a vector field which points roughly in the same direction as $-\nabla H$ along $H(q, p) = c$, i.e. to the inside of domain $H(q, p) \leqslant c$. And this geometrically explains why every trajectory goes to $(\pm 1, 0)$. But I think that you can't say beforehand to which of these two equilibria the trajectory will converge.